# For a table what is average pot?

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-theory

In a java based poker application, I have to find out average pot.As per front end screen looks like this metric is in percentage. When a player wins, I know the pot amount. Could it be derived from there?

Comment: Are you asking how to track the average pot size won by the player, or the average pot size at the table?

Comment: @Grinch91 , thanks for asking - it is average pot size at the table I guess. But there is %age also? what is 100% here?

Comment: So I believe, could be very wrong here, but online poker rooms if they offer that percentage only track the last X hands. I think I've read before it's between the last 50 to 200 hands at the table.